# Dynamic row Spanning in ag grid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ag-grid

I am working on row spanning in ag-grid, we can set fixed [row spanning](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-spanning/) in ag-grid. But I need to achieve dynamic row spanning shown in  below screenshot.

[image]

any help appreciated.

I am unable to visualize this thing because in row spanning of ag-grid, you can mention at the coldef level. i.e you are going to rowspanning in 4 rows or 3 rows etc

Comment: Adding a Sample StackBlitz with the current state of the grid would certainly help answerers get a starting point. :) If possible, can you please add one to the question?

Comment: can you please add some amount of code you tried and some where its getting failed. Code will explain more than link and screen shot.

Comment: I am unable to visualize this thing because in row spanning of ag-grid, you can mention at the coldef level. i.e you are going to rowspanning in 4 rows or 3 rows etc